# too much recursion underscore 1.4.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm having this problem.

```
too much recursion
```

and it points to underscore.js

```
// Extend a given object with all the properties in passed-in object(s).
_.extend = function(obj) {
  each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
     if (source) {
       for (var prop in source) {
          obj[prop] = source[prop];
       }
     }
  });
return obj;
};
```

By the way I'm using Backbone 0.9.10, jQuery 1.8.2, jQuery Mobile 1.2.0, require 2.1.4, and underscore 1.4.4

Here is my main.js

```
require.config({
paths:{
    jquery : 'libs/jQuery/1.8.2/jquery-1.8.2',
    mobile : 'libs/jQuery/jMobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0',
    base64 : 'libs/base64/webtoolkit.base64',
    backbone : 'libs/backbone/0.9.10/backbone',
    localstorage : 'libs/backbone/localstorage/backbone.localStorage',
    underscore : 'libs/underscore/1.4.4/underscore',
    text : 'libs/require/2.1.4/text/text',
    template : '../template'
},

 shim: {
    backbone: { deps: ["underscore", "jquery", "mobile"], exports: "Backbone" },
    underscore: { exports: "_" }
}

});

require([
// Load our app module and pass it to our definition function
'router'
], function(Router){

Router.initialize();
});
```

So my question is does Backbone 0.9.10 incompatible with underscore 1.4.4? Also they are both AMD versions I got hte https://github.com/amdjs.

When I try to downgrade Backbone to 0.9.2 while underscore is 1.4.4 it works the problem is I want Backbone to be updated. Any Ideas? Thanks

Comment: `_.extend` itself is not recursive. What's the stack trace?

Comment: Just to answer your question, Backbone 0.9.10 is compatible with underscore 1.4.4. Most likely your issue is not related to underscore's `extend` directly, that's just the method that happens to create the call stack frame that exceeds the maximum allowed. As Bergi suggested, the solution is in the stack trace.

Comment: sorry for being so dumb but how would I retrieve the stack trace? I'm using firefox and firebug

Comment: It should be part of the error which is logged in the console; maybe you need to expand it to show all properties